# C# Spawning random prefabs at random spawn points

Tags: c#, list, loops, unity-game-engine

Ok I'm trying to do 2 things :

1- Once a prefab is spawned, it should not spawn a second time

2- Once a spawn point is used for a prefab, it should not be used a second time (so two objects don't spawn at the same location)

Been trying to do this with lists. The problem I have is with removing the right items in the lists in a while loop, it seems to be problematic. The objects all spawn at the same spawn point and I don't know why.

Here's my code:

```
public List<GameObject> myList = new List<GameObject>();
 public List<GameObject> spawnPoint = new List<GameObject>();



 void Start () {


 Debug.Log ("Total objects to spawn now is " + myList.Count);



         if(myList.Count == 0){
             Debug.Log ("No Objects to spawn");
         } else {

             if(spawnPoint.Count ==0)
             {
                 Debug.Log ("No more spawn points");
             } else {

             while (myList.Count > 0) {

                 GameObject itemToSpawn = myList [Random.Range (0, myList.Count)];
                 GameObject spawns = spawnPoint [Random.Range (0, spawnPoint.Count)];
                 Vector3 position = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("replace").transform.position;
                 GameObject myItem = Instantiate (itemToSpawn, position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                 myList.Remove (itemToSpawn);
                 Debug.Log ("Total item now is " + myList.Count);
                 spawnPoint.Remove (spawns);
                 Debug.Log ("Total spawn points now is " + spawnPoint.Count);
                 DestroyObject (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("replace"));

             }
             }

         }

     }
```

}

Comment: Is better way to use Stack or Queue instead of List. You can simply learn an use it. but you should know these types are not serializable and will not be shown in the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue is you aren't using the different spawn points in your list as the input transform of your new `myItem` GameObject. You keep using the position of the Game Object you find with the tag `"replace"`, but nothing in your loop changes which GameObject this will be. I assume the objects in that list contain the `"replace"` tag, but you're never actually adding or removing any from the scene, so whichever object it finds with that tag will stay the same. You're getting a reference to a variable in the `spawnPoint` list, but then you never do anything with it before removing it from the list.  You'll likely want to set it up so that you can just do something like this:

```
Vector3 position = spawns.GetComponent<Transform>().position;
```

I agree with High that you should switch to a Stack or Queue, but no matter what you iterate through make sure you're getting the information you think you are.

Comment: You say I don't remove the object, but what about my last line?  DestroyObject (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("replace"));

Comment: Apologies, I was sloppy and missed it. You still aren't instantiating a new version of it each loop though.  If you want to use that method you'll need to instantiate `spawns` before trying to find it by tag in your scene.

Comment: I see, though I'm not sure. How would you code it? Just to make it more clear, the spawn points are fixed objects in the scenes, so I don't know why I would instantiate them at runtime. The reason is that way I make it more simple and avoid dealing with intersecting objects etc. So what I want to do is spawn a random list of objects only once each, at random predefined spawn points, and once a spawn point is used, it is not used again.

Comment: If your `spawnPoint` list already contains the appropriate GameObjects, then just update `position` as I had in my original answer.